# Area of the shaded area - Olympiad Math Past Paper Question

Tags: contest-math, area

I was going through some past Olympiad math papers and was stumped by the following question:

[image: area]

I couldn’t find a way to subtract the triangle, the unit square and the other negative spaces since they were overlapping each other.

How would I go about solving this question and other related questions? How would I add and subtract the negative spaces to get the area I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower shaded sector can be seen, by parallel lines and symmetry, to complement the larger shaded sector in the top right to form a full quarter circle, of area $\pi/4$. The remaining sector is half, because we have squares and the diagonal makes a $45^\circ$ angle, of a quarter circle so it has area $\pi/8$.

Together the shaded area makes $\frac{3}{8}\pi$.

As for tips, I personally dislike classical geometry and tend to do its problems with great reluctance when in a maths challenge (maths challenges *love* these problems for some reason!). However, maths challenges worth their salt always will go for problems, whether in geometry or not, that can be solved using a shortcut change in perspective. Here the trick was to see the shaded areas complement each other; harder questions will have a similar trick, but not one that geometrically annoyed people like myself can see very well! If the problem looks intractable, it usually will be in these challenges *bar the hidden shortcut*.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks for the answer! Now I know I can use symmetric properties to calculate this area. +1 and marked correct (oops, my account somehow says I can only mark it correct in 10 minutes, will do later)

Comment: I have some commentary on how to approach these too @Tyrcnex

Comment: Shortcuts are the one thing I’m bad at :)

Comment: @Tyrcnex Me too! Geometry is usually not my thing. If you want practice, the UKMT challenges (UK based Olympiads for all secondary school ages) have many number theory/geometry problems like this together with full solutions; years of archives for the senior challenge can be found [here](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/competitions/solo/senior-mathematical-challenge/archive).